# How do I determine which UIView superview is causing the subview to have userInteractionEnabled = NO?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a UIView that is showing up with userInteractionEnabled = NO and I can't figure out why. The settings in Interface Builder have all the views checked for userInteractionEnabled and nothing in the code sets the user interaction to NO. If I inspect the values during debugging,  however, the view and all superviews have userInteractionEnabled == NO.

I used the following code in the view controller to loop all the views and inspect their interaction status and even explicitly set the enabled value to YES:

```
BOOL *isEnabled = self.someView.userInteractionEnabled;
NSArray *_allViews = self.someView.window.subviews;
for (UIView *currentView in _allViews) {
    currentView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    isEnabled = currentView.userInteractionEnabled;
}
isEnabled = self.someView.userInteractionEnabled;
```

At each step in the process the isEnabled variable is always NO even though I set the user interaction to YES.

What could I be missing here?

EDIT:

Adding the debug code from @rmaddy plus a little extra I get this:

```
UIView *view = self.someView;
while (view) {
    isEnabled = view.userInteractionEnabled;
    if (!view.userInteractionEnabled) {
        NSLog(@"view is not enabled: %@", view);
        view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
    view = view.superview;
}
```

When I step through that the isEnabled variable is always NO, but the if (!view.userInteractionEnabled) logic never occurs. How can it be both? Is there something about Objective-C BOOL that I don't understand? How can the value of isEnabled be NO in the debugger yet the if (!view.userInteractionEnabled) condition never applies?

Very confused now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try starting at the subview and walk up the superview chain.

```
UIView *view = self.someView;
while (view) {
    if (!view.userInteractionEnabled) {
        NSLog(@"view is not enabled: %@", view);
        view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
    view = view.superview;
}
```

Comment: Ok, now I'm really confused. I added your debug code and no NSLogs are printed. All views show as userInteractionEnabled = NO, yet the if condition never fires. See the expanded edit in my OP.

Comment: I just noticed that you declare `isEnabled` as `BOOL *` instead of just `BOOL`. Get rid of the asterisk.

Comment: Right you are! I should have seen the *. So now I can see that all the views are really enabled. My problem lies elsewhere. Thanks for the help!